# Ubuntu 18.04 crashes when downloading large files

Tags: 18.04, crash, downloads

I have a Ubuntu system 18.04, my PC has i7 core and GPU rtx 2070, when I download large files either from firefox or wget my system crashes.

also from the syslog i got something like:

BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: 0000050000000000
PF supervisor read access in kernel
PF: error_code(0x0000) - not present page

also from doing free -h I get:

`total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        2.3G         21G        201M        7.5G         28G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G`

and from sysctl vm.swappiness i get:

`sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness/: Not a director`

and from checking `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e`:

`Apr 12 17:22:43 michalislazarou-System-Product-Name kernel: ucsi_ccg 0-0008: failed to reset PPM!
Apr 12 17:22:43 michalislazarou-System-Product-Name kernel: ucsi_ccg 0-0008: PPM init failed (-110)
Apr 12 17:23:45 michalislazarou-System-Product-Name kernel: BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: ffffa36c15823008`

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's logs.

Comment: Hey guys I have updated my question, I would be grateful if you can give me some insights on this problem, do you think is a hardware problem?